# Create nested samba shares with different user access

Tags: server, permissions, samba

I am working at a small company and am the most tech-savy so I am in charge of setting up the server.  I chose linux because of it being free and less malware prone.  I am a novice linux user. I have been figuring it out for a couple of weeks now but am wondering how to clean up my setup.

Currently I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS and have samba and openvpn setup to access the shares locally and from offsite.  Right now I have 3 separate shares setup, Owners, Admin(administration), and General.  They are setup and work fine however it is a lot of drives to map.  For myself I would have to map all 3 for local access and then 3 more for offsite vpn access.  This works but is kind of ugly.

What I was hoping to do was have one folder with the others as sub-directories for example make the top level owner and put all specific stuff in there and create a directory inside of owner called admin, in admin then place their specific files and then create a directory called general inside of admin.

The share would look like

[Owner]

path= /Owner

valid users= owner1 owner2

.

.

[Admin]

path= /Owner/Admin

valid users= owner1 owner2 admin1 admin2

.

.

[General]

path= /Owner/Admin/General

Valid users= owner1 owner2 admin1 admin2 gen1 gen2 .....

.

.

So then I could map one drive on every computer and owner would be able to access the top level and all the way down.  When I mapped for Admin I would just map \Server\Admin and they wouldn't even see the parent directory.

When I tried this I thought it worked at first but then upon retrying when mapping the drive I got access denied when using credentials of anyone not on the top level directory.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!